# XSLT ouputs to UTF-8 but template has non-UTF characters

Tags: xml, xslt, utf-8

**Warning: I did not write the XSLT referenced here**

I have an XSL that has encoding on xsl:output set to UTF-8.
The XSL document declares a variable firstTierLabel which it then use.

```xml
<xsl:template name="genFirstTierTD">
    <xsl:param name="rowspan"/>
    <xsl:param name="firstTierLabel"/>
    <td class="headFirst"  colspan="1">
        <xsl:attribute name="rowspan"><xsl:value-of select="$rowspan"/></xsl:attribute>
        <span>
            <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="'firstLevelText'"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="$firstTierLabel"/>
        </span>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

The XML files I have use this XSLT to transform a line such as:

```xml
<field name="LINE 1 –" label="LINE 1 –">
    <field2 name="DATE AND TIME" label="DATE AND TIME" type="xsd:dateTime">
        <tooltip> DTG </tooltip>
        <cssClass>ncssHeaderValDtg</cssClass>
    </field2>
</field>
```

Into part of a table row that *should* look something like:

```
| LINE 1 - | DATE AND TIME             |
```

But what I'm getting back is (notice the ? after "LINE 1"):

```
| LINE 1 ? | DATE AND TIME             |
```

Now I have 182 of these files, some with 200+ lines which I have little-to-no control over...is there any way I can convert that non-UTF character?

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with your `<xsl:output>` setting, if the character is not decoded on the way in.  Check the encoding of the *reader* on the *input document*.  That's where you need to ensure that the bytes are understood.

Comment: Agreed. The chances are that the encoding of the input XML file does not match its XML declaration. Most likely, the file has no XML declaration, which means UTF-8 is assumed, but the actual encoding is something like Windows CP-1252.